# como hago para subir una imagen en java? tengo el siguiente codigo

Tags: java, html, upload

Si me inserta a la base de datos el nombre de la imagen pero no me guarda la imagen en la ruta que le doy me sale el siguiente error:

> Exception: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or
>   multipart/form-data stream, content type header is nullException: the
>   request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data
>   stream, content type header is
>   nullorg.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory@7641070d

```
 <form action="uploadfile" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="file_name" name="nombre">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="Seleccione Imagen"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBIR ARCHIVO"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

y uso javascript para separar una ruta falsa que me da y solo selecciono el nombre de la imagen:

```
   $(function(){
       $("#file").change(function(){
            var name = $("#file").val();
            var arreglo = name.split("\\"); 
            console.log(arreglo);
            var image_name = arreglo[2];
            $("#file_name").val(image_name);
       });
   });
```

en el servlet tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
try{
         ConectaDB conect = new ConectaDB();
          Connection c = conect.conectar();
          String archivo = request.getParameter("file");  
          System.out.println(archivo);
          String nombre = "venta";
          String img_producto= "imagenes/"+archivo;
          int id_categoria=2;
          float precio = 2200;
          int stock = 10;

          String query = "INSERT INTO productos(nombre,img_producto,id_categoria, precio,stock) VALUES ('"+nombre+"','"+img_producto+"','"+id_categoria+"','"+precio+"','"+stock+"');";
            Statement stm = c.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate(query);
            stm.close();
            c.close();
            System.out.println(query);
        }catch(SQLException sqlx) {

            sqlx.printStackTrace();

        }
            String archivourl = /home/luis/Escritorio/prueba/web/imagenes";

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            factory.setSizeThreshold(1024);

            factory.setRepository(new File(archivourl));

            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);


            try{

                List<FileItem> partes = upload.parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem items: partes){
                    File file = new File(archivourl,items.getName());
                    items.write(file);
                }
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                out.print("<h2>ARCHIVO CORRECTAMENTE SUBIDO.....</h2>"+"\n\n"+"<a href='index.jsp'>VOVLER AL MENU</a>");

            }catch(Exception e){
                out.print("Exception: "+e.getMessage()+"");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Usar `get` con un `multipart/form-data` es muy raro, pero no me atrevería a decir que es el único problema que tienes. Lo de usar el JavaScript para cambiar la ruta del campo `file` es rarísimo, también.

Comment: el multipart es para POST https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1 y  https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype

Answer (score 0):

el problema consiste en que estas utilizando un metodo GET para el envio del formulario. Cuando  usas GET se interpreta que los parametros van en la URL de la petición. Debes usar POST de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="uploadfile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="file_name" name="nombre">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="Seleccione Imagen"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBIR ARCHIVO"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: votar en contra
accept
si funciona solo query de la inserccion pero me sale otro error.

INSERT INTO productos(nombre,img_producto,id_categoria, precio,stock) VALUES ('productos','imagenes/sharingan.jpg','2','2200.0','10'); Exception: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is nu